# Why is ExecutorChannel.onInit() resetting the dispatcher?

Tags: spring-integration

I have a simple, working Spring Integration application the moves messages from an inbound RabbitMQ gateway, through a handler chain and into a MongoDB database.  When I changed from a direct channel to an executor channel, I started getting subscriber errors.  Watching things in the debugger I saw that after I set up the ExecutorChannel bean, the onInit() method gets triggered and resets everything to default values.  I cannot figure out why the code would be structured to do this?  I looked at DirectChannel.onInit() and it only modifies things if values have not previously been set. Any ideas? I am using Spring Integration 4.1.2.

```
// from
@Bean
DirectChannel uploadChannel( MessageHandlerChain uploadMessageHandlerChain ) {
    def bean = new DirectChannel()
    bean.subscribe( uploadMessageHandlerChain )
    bean
}

// to
@Bean
ExecutorChannel uploadChannel( MessageHandlerChain uploadMessageHandlerChain ) {
    def bean = new ExecutorChannel( Executors.newCachedThreadPool() )
    bean.subscribe( uploadMessageHandlerChain )
    bean
}

org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create channels using XML application context, you first define the channel and after you use it in an EIP pattern:

```
<int:channel id="directChannel"/>
<int:service-activator input-channel="directChannel"/>
```

This allows in my opinion a better separation of concern. Same pattern must be used with java configuration, first declare your channel then declare `MessageHandlerChain` and subscribe to the channel

```
@Bean
ExecutorChannel uploadChannel() {
    def bean = new ExecutorChannel( Executors.newCachedThreadPool() )
    bean
}

@Bean
MessageHandlerChain uploadMessageHandlerChain(){
    def uploadMessageHandlerChain = new MessageHandlerChain()
    uploadChannel().subscribe(uploadMessageHandlerChain)
    uploadMessageHandlerChain
}
```

Comment: Nicolas, that ordering was exactly what I needed.  Thank you.

Comment: Guys, it is interesting for me why `@ServiceActivator` on that `MessageHandlerChain` `@Bean` isn't fit for you? Even if that `subscribe` stuff works well you don't have an endpoint there and you won't be able to `stop` listening from the channel at runtime. The `<int:service-activator>` creates exactly endpoint and `MessageHandler`. The same is done by the annotation mention above.

Comment: Why an `SubscribableChannel#unsubscribe` is not possible at runtime ? Whatever, if the subscription never change, I agree with you.